# Finding nearest sumElement combination in list

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I'm having some problem with finding nearest sumElement combination in list.

Example:

This is my list:

```
 list = {32183,15883,26917,25459,22757,25236,1657}
 list.Sum = 150092
```

And now I'm dividing

```
 list.Sum / z
 z = variable(user Input - in this example it's 3)
```

and I get

```
50031
```

Now I want to find closest number from listElement summs.

Closest to 50031 is

```
 32183 + 15883 = 48066
       or
 32183 + 15883 + 26917 = 74983
```

So I'm choosing 48066, next I want to find next element but we had to skip already counted elements(in this case I had to skip 32183 + 15883)

So now we can use only these elements 26917,25459,22757,25236,1657(not counted yet)

```
  26917 + 25459 = 52376
        or
  26917 + 25459 + 22757 = 75133
```

So I'm choosing 52376

and we doing this z(variable) times

*We can sum elements in this order for exmaple we can't add*

```
 32183 + 15883 + 1657
```

*Because this skip couple list elements*

*We can sum elements in this sort, we CAN'T sort list.*
We can't do it because these numbers are lines amount from .csv file so I had to do it in this order.

For now I had:

```
for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
{
    mid = suma/z ;

    najbliższy = listSum.Aggregate((x, y) => Math.Abs(x - mid) < Math.Abs(y - mid) ? x : y);
}
```

It finds me the 1st element (correctly) but I don't know how to loop it correctly. So I got only first element and in this example I need 3.

Can anyone help me to accomplish this?

Comment: `Closest number` means the *single* number that is closes to another. Yet your code tries to find the *combination of numbers* that is closest to another. Please edit your title and text to explain what you want

Comment: Are the numbers you add together always adjacent in the list? Or can there be gaps?

Comment: do list has n items or only 7 items ?

Comment: list has n items - i never know how many(I'm reading it from file)

Comment: "we CAN'T sort list" - surely you can make a copy of the list and sort that, what is preventing this?

Comment: panagiotis, you're right, already change it

Comment: @Pro100 The problem probably has a specific name and there are algorithms to calculate this that are faster than calculating the sum of all combinations (hint: search for ways to calculate all combinations. There are a lot of related questions in SO)

Comment: Sounds like a variation of the `Knapsack problem`

Comment: Important: Can the list contain negative numbers? If not, there's an obvious optimisation.

Comment: In the example you take subsets of 2 and 3 numbers, can the subsets be of any size? - still confuded, is the size of the subset equal to the size of the list over z?

Comment: @grek40 Or a special case of the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#cite_note-MartelloToth-1) which is itself a subset of the knapsack problem.

Comment: @Pro100 please explain the *actual problem statement*, not how you tried to solve it. As you see, there are many optimization problems that look like what you try to do, but you force people to guess (eg what the ... is z ?). Posting the actual name of the problem would be great

Comment: @MatthewWatson no, it's impossible. Elements always will be possitive.

Comment: Can we choose `32183 + 15883 + 1657 == 49723`?

Comment: create a 2 properties object off each of them, one contains the value, one contains the original index, combine to an array of objects, and then sort that array. this makes it any easier ?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko no, as I said we can adding number in this order and by doing it this way you skip couple numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have wrote code that seems to do what you describe. The idea is to keep a `bin` where the code will be adding contiguous numbers.

Contiguous because you say that we can't add if we

> skip couple list elements

Now, when deciding to add to the `bin`, it will always try to do so if the total of the `bin` is less than the target value. And will only add if adding the new value makes the total closer to the target value. If those criteria are not met, then the number will not be added to the `bin`.

So, instead if the code decides to not add a number to the `bin`, then it will create a new `bin`. Now, at all times the best `bin` so far is stored, once the code is done with a `bin`, it compares it to that one and if it is better then replace it, if it is not just discard the current `bin` and start over.

These are my parameters:

```
var list = new List<int>{32183,15883,26917,25459,22757,25236,1657};
var sum = list.Sum();
var z = 3; // user input
var mid = (int)Math.Ceiling(sum / (double)z); // cutout point
```

Note: I'm using Ceiling for rounding because the `sum` (150092) divided by 3 is 50030.666666...

```
var bin = new List<int>();
var binTotal = 0;
var bestBin = bin;
var bestBinTotal = binTotal;
var candidatesCount = 0;

for(var index = 0; index < list.Count; index++)
{
    var current = list[index];
    var keep =
        (
            // The total of the bin is yet to reach the cutout point
            binTotal < mid
            // And adding the current will make it clouser
            && Math.Abs(mid - (binTotal + current)) < Math.Abs(mid - binTotal)
        )
        // but if this is the last candidate, screw that and add anyway
        || candidatesCount == (z - 1);
    if (keep)
    {
        bin.Add(current);
        binTotal += current;
    }
    else
    {
        candidatesCount++;
        if (Math.Abs(mid - binTotal) < Math.Abs(mid - bestBinTotal))
        {
            bestBin = bin;
            bestBinTotal = binTotal;
        }
        bin = new List<int>{current}; // because we didn't add it
        binTotal = current;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Result: {"+ string.Join(", ", bestBin) +"}; Total: " + bestBinTotal);
```

The output is `Result: {32183, 15883}; Total: 48066`

We can see that the distance from `48066` to `50031` is `1965`, while the distance from `50031` to `52376` is `2345`. So the code correctly decides that `48066` is closer.

Note: tested on LinqPad.

---

In fact the bins are only for storing the selected values, so if you don't need that you can remove them. If instead what you want is all the candidates you can modify the code as follows:

```
var candidates = new List<int>();
var binTotal = 0;
var bestBinTotal = binTotal;

for(var index = 0; index < list.Count; index++)
{
    var current = list[index];
    var keep =
        (
            // The total of the bin is yet to reach the cutout point
            binTotal < mid
            // And adding the current will make it clouser
            && Math.Abs(mid - (binTotal + current)) < Math.Abs(mid - binTotal)
        )
        // but if this is the last candidate, screw that and add anyway
        || candidates.Count == (z - 1);
    if (keep)
    {
        binTotal += current;
    }
    else
    {
        candidates.Add(binTotal);
        if (Math.Abs(mid - binTotal) < Math.Abs(mid - bestBinTotal))
        {
            bestBinTotal = binTotal;
        }
        binTotal = current; // because we didn't add it
    }
}

// Fix to add the final candidate:

candidates.Add(binTotal);

Console.WriteLine("Result: {"+ string.Join(", ", candidates) +"}; Best: " + bestBinTotal);
```

The output is `Result: {48066, 52376, 49650}; Best: 48066`

Comment: Can I contact you any way ?

Comment: @Pro100 tell me the subject. I'm unsure if you want to talk about something on topic on this question. And if it is offtopic, I don't know if its a public or private matter. Edit: this is perfectly fine as long as we stay on topic.

Comment: @Thearot It's about this topic but I don't want to mess here so I hope we could move to chat so people will still be able to see it.

Comment: @Pro100 alright, I created a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124736/chat-for-finding-nearest-sumelement-combination-in-list) for this question.

Comment: @Thearot please check chat

Answer (score 3):

The output from the following code is:

```
Target = 50031

32183 15883 Total: 48066
26917 25459 Total: 52376
22757 25236 1657 Total: 49650
```

You just need to call FindSubsetsForTotal() to receive a sequence of all the subsets, that you can just iterate over.

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var numbers = new[] {32183, 15883, 26917, 25459, 22757, 25236, 1657};
            int target = 50031;

            foreach (var subset in FindSubsetsForTotal(numbers, target))
            {
                int subtotal = 0;

                for (int i = subset.Item1; i <= subset.Item2; ++i)
                {
                    Console.Write(numbers[i] + " ");
                    subtotal += numbers[i];
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Total: " + subtotal);
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> FindSubsetsForTotal(IList<int> numbers, int target)
        {
            int i = 0;

            while (i < numbers.Count)
            {
                int end = endIndexOfNearestSum(numbers, i, target);
                yield return new Tuple<int, int>(i, end); // The subset is from i..end inclusive. Return it.
                i = end + 1;                              // On to the next subset.
            }
        }

        static int endIndexOfNearestSum(IList<int> numbers, int start, int target)
        {
            int sumSoFar    = 0;
            int previousSum = 0;

            for (int i = start; i < numbers.Count; ++i)
            {
                sumSoFar += numbers[i];

                if (sumSoFar > target)
                {
                    if (Math.Abs(sumSoFar - target) < Math.Abs(previousSum - target))
                        return i;

                    return i - 1;
                }

                previousSum = sumSoFar;
            }

            return numbers.Count - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is my second attempt. If you want consequent closest sums i.e. for

```
list   = {32183, 15883, 26917, 25459, 22757, 25236, 1657 ...
target = 50031
answer = {48066, 52376, 49650, ...
```

You can try summing `item`s up to the `target` and then decide wether to *take* the `item` (and return the value that's bigger than `target`) or *leave* the `item` (and return the value samller than `target`)

```
private static IEnumerable<int> Approximations(IEnumerable<int> values, int target) {
  int sum = 0;
  bool first = true; // we have to take at least one item

  foreach (var item in values) {
    if (sum + item < target || first) {
      first = false;

      sum += item;
    }
    else {
      if (sum + item - target < target - sum) {
        yield return sum + item; // better to take the item

        sum = 0;
        first = true;
      }
      else {
        yield return sum; // better to leave the item

        sum = item;
      }
    }
  }

  if (first) // nothing has been taken
    yield break; 

  yield return sum;
}
```

Test

```
 List<int> list = new List<int>() { 32183, 15883, 26917, 25459, 22757, 25236, 1657 };

 int z = 3;
 int target = list.Sum() / z; // 50031

 // 48066, 52376, 49650
 string answer = string.Join(", ", Approximations(list, target));
```

Please, notice that in case of *file* you have no need to read the *entire* file (if `target` doesn't depend on the file containt):

```
 var solution = Approximations(File
   .ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt")
   .Select(line => int.Parse(line)),
   50031);
```

Comment: I think you understood it wrong. As far as I understand, a valid solution would also include `32183 + 26917`, skipping some index in between.

Comment: @grek40: I see; I've totally rebuild the solution

Comment: @grek40 The OP explicitly says that you can't skip elements (Quote: `for exmaple we can't add ... Because this skip couple list elements`)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Ok, but that was edited into the question about the same time as I wrote my comment ;).

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be:

```
  class Program
  {
    static IEnumerable<int> EnumNearestSums(IList<int> list, int z)
    {
      var target = (int)(list.Sum() / (double)z + 0.5);
      var index = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
      {
        var sum = 0;
        for (int j = index; j < list.Count; j++)
        {
          index++;
          var tmp = sum + list[j];
          if (tmp > target)
          {
            if (Math.Abs(target - sum) < Math.Abs(target - tmp))
            {
              index--;
            }
            else
            {
              sum = tmp;
            }
            break;
          }
          else
          {
            sum = tmp;
          }
        }
        yield return sum;
      }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var list = new[] { 32183, 15883, 26917, 25459, 22757, 25236, 1657 };
      var z = 3;

      foreach (var num in EnumNearestSums(list, z))
      {
        Console.WriteLine(num);
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

Result:
48066
52376
49650